# display and manipulate Images with gwidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

Dear stackexchange world. I would like to ask a question about a problem I am facing with a small program that I am writing in R. 
I have written a code that lets you import an image and manipulate it with the `EBImage()` library. I use `gWidgets()` library so the user can do dynamic manipulation. The code is this one:

```
library("EBImage")
library("gWidgets2")
setwd(choose.dir())
imageinput<-file.choose()
image<-readImage(imageinput)

##defininig the color mode
colorimage<-c(Greymode="gray",RGBmode="rgb")


updateImage <-function (h,...) {

image1<-((svalue(brightness)+image*svalue(contrast))^(svalue(gamma)))
image2<-channel(image1,colorimage[svalue(colormode)])
display(image2)
}

colormode <- gradio(names(colorimage), horizontal=FALSE,handler=updateImage)
brightness<-gslider(from=-1,to=1,by=.1, value=0,handler=updateImage)
contrast <- gslider(from=0,to=10,by=.1, value=1,handler=updateImage)
gamma <- gslider(from=0,to=10,by=0.1, value=1,handler=updateImage)


window <- gwindow("Image Editing")


BigGroup <- ggroup(cont=window)
group <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container=BigGroup)
tmp <- gframe("Colormode", container=group)
add(tmp, colormode)
tmp <- gframe("Brightness", container=group)
add(tmp, brightness, expand=TRUE)
tmp <- gframe("Contrast", container=group)
add(tmp, contrast, expand=TRUE)
tmp <- gframe("Gamma", container=group)
add(tmp, gamma, expand=TRUE)
```

But I am facing a problem (as I posted in a previous question, but I solved some issues and I thought it would be good to repost a new one with better code and many problems solved). The problem is that I cannot display in the gWidgets GUI I have constructed the image and how it is dynamically edited. Although there is a way to see the image with the `display()` function of the EBImage package, it is not the one I want because it is displayed in the web browser and not in the GUI.

I would appreciate if someone has any idea what I could do to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how render an image to the current interactive device, but if you can, the you can use `ggraphics` with `cairoDevice`. Alternatively, you can use `writeImage` to write to an image file and display that through `gimage`. This is usually responsive enough, though maybe not with large images.

Comment: I have used gimage but the problem like the way you said, but the broblem was that the image was not refreshed when there was a change. ggraphics and cairoDevice I have never used them before. @jverzani Mr Verzani are you the one involved with the writing of the gWidgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is finished and its working thank to suggestions of  John Verzani  Stéphane Laurent. It was a bit tricky but at the end it worked!
the code is this:

```
library("EBImage")
library("gWidgets2")
setwd(choose.dir())
imageinput<-file.choose()
image<-readImage(imageinput)

##defininig the color mode
colorimage<-c(RGBmode="rgb",Greymode="gray")


updateImage <-function (h,...) {
image1<-((svalue(brightness)+image*svalue(contrast))^(svalue(gamma)))
image2<-channel(image1,colorimage[svalue(colormode)])
imageout<-writeImage(image2,"imageout.jpeg")
svalue(img)<-"imageout.jpeg"
}

colormode <- gradio(names(colorimage), horizontal=FALSE,handler=updateImage)
brightness<-gslider(from=-1,to=1,by=.1, value=0,handler=updateImage)
contrast <- gslider(from=0,to=10,by=.1, value=1,handler=updateImage)
gamma <- gslider(from=0,to=10,by=0.1, value=1,handler=updateImage)


window <- gwindow("Image Editing")

BigGroup <- ggroup(cont=window)
group <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container=BigGroup)
tmp <- gframe("Colormode", container=group)
add(tmp, colormode)
tmp <- gframe("Brightness", container=group)
add(tmp, brightness, expand=TRUE)
tmp <- gframe("Contrast", container=group)
add(tmp, contrast, expand=TRUE)
tmp <- gframe("Gamma", container=group)
add(tmp, gamma, expand=TRUE)
img <- gimage(imageinput,container=BigGroup)
```

There should be created a new frame that would contain the graphics (gimage) but the value of the image displayed should be renewed after every editing. So the svalue should be in the function.

Comment: You need to update the image held by gimage. If you create the widget with `img <- gimage(...)`, then use `svalue(img) <- file_name` to update the widget.

Comment: I cannot figure it out how to do what you are suggesting. Maybe my knowledge on this is not so deep so I can understand it. If you could explain how the code should be written...because I am fighting with the text some hours now...and google doesn't help much...there is not so much information on gwidgets (except your pdfs with examples) on the net so I can combine what you are suggesting with any example to see how it is done. :/

Comment: Hello Tony. When you make progress but your problem is not solved, you should edit your first question instead of opening an answer.

Comment: Tony, try this : `gplot <- ggraphics(container=BigGroup)`, then `img <- gimage(image0,container=gplot)`, where `image0` is your first image file, and then when you create a new image file `image1`, do `svalue(img)<-image1`.